# How to validate non-required RequestParam is not blank?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-restcontroller

I'm using validators in my spring controllers. If `@RequestParam` is required there is no problem, i can check String with `@NotBlank`. But if `@RequestParam` is  optional, i can't use it with `@NotBlank`, because this parameter is optional and sometimes can be null.
I want to validate `@NotBlank` if String is not null. Is there any constraint help me?

```
@RequestParam @NotBlank String name
```

working perfectly. I have problem with `required=false`
if client don't send optional description parameter, validation fails.

```
@PatchMapping("/role/{id}") 
public ResponseEntity<?> updateRole(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable @Positive Integer id,
                                   @RequestParam @NotBlank String name,
                                   @RequestParam(required = false) @NotBlank String description)
```

I want to validate `@NotBlank` if description is not `null`.

```
`@RequestParam(required = false) @NotBlank String description`
```

If i use like that, i got "Input validation failed!".

Comment: try to put `@Valid` annotation

Comment: @dehasi i think, i don't need `@Valid` . I have `@Validated` annotation with my controller class and other validations works. But i tried `@RequestParam(required = false) @Valid @NotBlank String description` and it not works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom validator for this.

**Interface**

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = YourValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotBlankIfPresent{

    String message() default "Error MEssage";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Your Validator Class**

```
public class YourValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotBlankIfPresent, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (s == null) {
            return true;
        }
        
        return !s.isBlank();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not right approach to validate @RequestParam. You have to validate in your code
 if it is blank then `throw new IllegalArgumentException("{\"error\":\"The parameter is invalid\"}"`

Comment: Why this is not right approach? We generally use javax.constraints for validation. simple and easy.

Comment: @EdwardD.Wilson : please check my answer in similar context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997703/the-validators-validated-valid-do-not-work-with-spring-and-tomee/53998229#53998229

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using `@RequestParam(required = false)` and `@NotBlank` together. 
Here is how the `@NotBlank` annotation works.

> a String field constrained with @NotBlank must be not null and the trimmed length must be greater than zero.

Maybe a workaround could be using a **default value** in your request param variable whenever you have `required = false`

Example:

```
@PatchMapping("/role/{id}") 
public ResponseEntity<?> updateRole(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable 
@Positive Integer id, @RequestParam @NotBlank String name,
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "adefaultvalue") @NotBlank String description) {
    if(description.equals("adefaultvalue") {
      // that means that the user did not send any value for this variable so you can 
     // add your validation logic here
    }
}
```

Please have in mind that the above code has not been tested